# How to get the time of tomorrow 1:30 AM?

Tags: python

I'm using the following expression to get the time of 1:30 AM tomorrow.

```
import datetime

t = datetime.date.today()
datetime.datetime.combine(t, datetime.time.min) + datetime.timedelta(hours=1, days=1, minutes=30)
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Put a look again at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70132738/941531), just now (after you Accepted it) added second part of answer, where did some corrections if it is last day of the month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your way of writing is totally alright, another way of achieving same task is:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYtBCsQgDADvviJHpVJ26bmPEWrRQxKRlMXXu7HY5jQzSUqTxLT1flZGOIJEyRghY@EqrxviH@yvrqrWmVIziX2ibTFUPdLdOtADMkma5WZvQOcIbcZBC3w9JL7GqxJmuiQqbx/nev8D)

```py
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
print(datetime(year = now.year, month = now.month,
    day = now.day + 1, hour = 1, minute = 30))
```

Output:

```
2021-11-28 01:30:00
```

---

Just figured out that the way of writing as above will not work for the last day of the month (`day + 1` will overflow number of days in a month), so it is better to do as following:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY3BCsMgDIbvPkWOyqRs9NyHERpQmInYlOHTu1ikOyyH8P1/kj@lSWRae0@5cBXYg6CkjIb4A9stlxvUt86Umkjs39Q2DFXPdGkZ6CEzSZzOxV4z2zSUnAGtx@/RaDu@JWh6O3Tx5SHyWSfmRKfgEOvTud6/)

```py
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(datetime.datetime(year = now.year, month = now.month, day = now.day)
    + datetime.timedelta(days = 1, hours = 1, minutes = 30))
```

Output:

```
2021-11-28 01:30:00
```

Comment: Note that this work for daylight savings time correctly, but I don't know if it matters in your situation. If it's all UTC it'll be correct, but if not, you have to correct for timezones.